# jquery.AutoComplete.js adaptive width

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `row[0]` is too long, the width of the yellow part does not adapt.

How can I solve this?

[image]

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var b = $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val();
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx?id=' + b,
        {
           max:10,
           formatItem: formatItem,
           //               width:300
           width: $("#p0").width() + $("#s0").width()
        }
        );

    });
    function formatItem(row) {
    return " <p id=\"p0\">"+row[0] +" </p>"+ " <span id=\"s0\">about&nbsp;13456Items</span>";
}
```

tks in advance!

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin is this? The old one or the one that is built into jquery-ui?

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your code:

```
width: $("#p0").width() + $("#s0").width()
```

Try increasing it first and then try using width %